# What's origin of the Chinese word for "time" (时间)?

Tags: etymology

I believe the Chinese word for time is 时间.

Does anybody know how to find out its origin? If there is a place where it is possible to know the origin of Chinese characters please share. Thank you

Answer (score 4):

The '日' radical of '時' indicates it is related to 'sun; day'

The '寺' /si4/ part in '時'/shi2/ is the phonics component

(*寺 means 'temple'.  As the phonics component of 時, the 'temple' meaning is irrelevant*)

> [時](http://www.shuowen.org/view/4172) means 'time; hour'
>
> *四時也; 本春秋冬夏之稱。引伸之爲凡嵗月日刻之用*
>
> Originally meant four **seasons** (四**時**), extended to mean 'years, months, days and hours' (**time**)

~

> 間 means 'space between; interval'

~

> **時間** means '**time**' (**intervals of days, hours**)

There are other time related words in Chinese:

> 光= light; 陰= shade
>
> **光陰**= light and shade= day and night= **time** (cycle of days and nights)

~

> 寒= cold; 暑= hot
>
> **寒暑**= cold and hot= winter and summer= **time** (cycle of seasons)

~

> 歲= year; 月= month
>
> **歲月**= year and month= **time** (passing of years and months)

Jeremy wrote:

> *if there is a place where it is possible to know the origin of Chinese characters please share*

You can find the origins of many Chinese characters in [說文解字](http://www.shuowen.org/) or just wiki it

Answer (score 0):

时: season
间: period

Period of season is time.

Helpful link for character details: http://www.zdic.net/z/1b/xs/65F6.htm